# Templates for Custom Modules in Sitefinity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

Simply put, how does one create templates for the List/Detail View of a Custom Module in Visual Studio.  I would like to be able to query for other members of the custom module in the detail view to allow for paging forward and back through the content for instance.  Perhaps in MVC if possible?

Comment: Hi Piotr, is this a custom module built using Module Builder?

Comment: @Ben, yes it has been built using Module Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a module created with module builder, you can create and edit module builder templates using Sitefinity's Visual Studio Plugin called [Thunder](http://www.sitefinity.com/resources/tools/sitefinity-thunder)

You'll need to be running the site off IIS, install the plugin through Visual Studio, then configure a connection to your site through the Connection Settings, image here but the video on the Sitefinty page above does a good job showing this as well:

[image]

Using the Sitefinity Explorer you'll be able to not only edit the default templates (details and list) that are created with each new custom content item created with module builder through Visual Studio but also all the templates for the built in content types in Sitefinity (News, Events, Blogs, Lists, etc.) image here:

[image]

Thunder is also not limited to widget template editing through Visual Studio, there is boiler plate code for custom widgets, configs, themes and host of other helpful tools to speed up development with Sitefinity.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, you can't create MVC templates for custom content types. You can create custom MVC widgets using Thunder however.